# Proper approach to get words like "dentistry", "dentist" from query like "dental" (and vice versa)

Tags: search, text, nlp, stemming

I'm somewhat familiar with stemming, but the stemming library I've been given to use for a project doesn't work very well for a case where I want to find related words like if I do a query for any of these:

"dental", "dentist", "dentistry"

I should get a match for the others. I've been looking into this and I'm learning about parts of speech I didn't even know existed, like pertainyms and troponyms so I'm wondering if there isn't a library out there that has a mapping between all of these different parts of speech that could give back the sort of match I'm looking for?

I've been searching on this and haven't found a whole lot that I can make sense of. I probably don't know the right terminology, etc and I would greatly appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Pertainyms and troponyms are not parts of speech, but word relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach common in IR is to stem all words in the index and the query itself. Meaning, documents containing the word 'dentistry' will be stemmed and stored in the index as 'dentist'. The keyword 'dental' is also stemmed as 'dentist' thereby matching  it in the index.

Comment: I think the stemming algorithm we have in place must not be optimal as it doesn't stem a word like "dentistry" or "dental" to "dentist" so I suppose thats where the issue lies

Comment: Yes! It's a trade between precision and recall. But the beauty of doing this stemming in both the query and the document is that you do not have to enumerate all possibilities (i.e., dentistry, dental) for a word like dentist. Rather, they are indexed or grouped already based on their stems. Though it's a precision issue, especially if your sample words are all stemmed to 'dent'.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).  WordNet is an organized ontology of words and concepts with links for various types of relations between words.  I'm not sure if it will have exactly the relationships you want, but it's probably a good start.  There are many interfaces in various programming languages (Java and Python that I've used; presumably many more).

Comment: cool, Java is what I would be using it from... it definitely has a lot of useful data, not sure if it will solve the exact issue but I can see how this could be useful for a number of things

Comment: Particularly, the word derivation relation may be what you need.